# monkey patch a block in a module in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

```
module Cequel
  module Record

    module Schema
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      extend Util::Forwardable

      included do
        class_attribute :table_name, instance_writer: false
        self.table_name = name.demodulize.tableize.to_sym unless name.nil? || self.table_name.present?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to monkey patch `included` block from this module in my rails application, but when I define the same code in initializer in rails I get

`included': Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern (ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks)`

[This](https://github.com/cequel/cequel/pull/364) is what I want to fix with a patch until this PR is merged, Is there any way to patch the included block?

Comment: your PR is merged so just point your gem to master ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start from the scratch in your initializer. That said, you should remove the module constant definition completely with

```
Cequel::Record.send :remove_const, :Schema
```

Now you can re-execute the snippet, defining `Schema` as you want: Ruby does not know anything about it anymore.